# Проблема передачи объектов из Hibernate на клиент, через Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

В процессе изучения java программирования, пишу для себя небольшой RESTful сервис с которым возникла проблема.

Для разработки RESTful сервиса использую Spring Boot и Hibernate. Суть проблемы: после введения связи один-к-многим между сущностями БД я не могу передать объекты считанные из БД на клиент. При записи в БД проблем нет.

Вот графическая схема БД:
[image: графическая схема БД]

При исполнение метода передачи объекта, возникает ошибка.

```
2016-06-15 20:24:36.631  WARN 1372 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandler ExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: prodinfo.models.Avtor["lkat"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: prodinfo.models.Avtor["lkat"])
```

Сам метод запроса и передачи объекта:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getlist")
@ResponseBody
public Avtor avtorout(String urladdress) {

    List<Avtor> avtorlist = avtorDao.getByUrladdress(urladdress);
    Avtor avtor = avtorlist.get(0);

    return avtor;
}
```

Метод getByUrladdress() из avtorDao:

```
public List<Avtor> getByUrladdress(String urladdress) {
    return entityManager.createQuery(
        "from Avtor where urladdress = :urladdress")
        .setParameter("urladdress", urladdress)
        .getResultList();
}
```

Модель сущности Avtor:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Avtor"
,schema="public"
)
public class Avtor implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@NotNull
@Type(type = "text")
private String urladdress;

@Type(type = "text")
private String avtorname;

private String update_avtor;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "title_lkat")
private Set<Lkat> lkat = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Lkat> getLkat() {
    return this.lkat;
}

public void setLkat(Set<Lkat> lkat) {
    this.lkat = lkat;
}

public void addLkat(Lkat lkat) {
    lkat.setAvtor(this);
    this.lkat.add(lkat);
}

public Avtor() {
}

public Avtor(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Avtor(String urladdress) {
    this.urladdress = urladdress;
}

public Avtor(String avtorname, String update_avtor) {
    this.avtorname = avtorname;
    this.update_avtor = update_avtor;
}

public Avtor(long id, String avtorname, String update_avtor) {
    this.id = id;
    this.avtorname = avtorname;
    this.update_avtor = update_avtor;
}

public Avtor(String urladdress, String avtorname, String update_avtor) {
    this.urladdress = urladdress;
    this.avtorname = avtorname;
    this.update_avtor = update_avtor;
}

public Avtor(long id, String urladdress, String avtorname, String update_avtor) {
    this.id = id;
    this.urladdress = urladdress;
    this.avtorname = avtorname;
    this.update_avtor = update_avtor;
}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUrladdress() {
    return urladdress;
}

public void setUrladdress(String urladdress) {
    this.urladdress = urladdress;
}

public String getAvtorname() {
    return avtorname;
}

public void setAvtorname(String avtorname) {
    this.avtorname = avtorname;
}

public String getUpdate_avtor() {
    return update_avtor;
}

public void setUpdate_avtor(String update_avtor) {
    this.update_avtor = update_avtor;
}

}
```

Т.к. без связи один-к-многим объекты передаются без проблем, возникает вопрос как правильно передавать объекты из БД со связями сущностей?

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что ваши сущности имеют ссылки друг на друга. В таком случае для Jackson требуется дополнительно отметить соответствующие поля аннотациями `@JsonManagedReference` и `@JsonBackReference`. Но обычно никто не отдает Entity наружу, вместо этого используют DTO.

Comment: К сожалению использование `@JsonManagedReference` и `@JsonBackReference` не помогло решить проблему.

Comment: Проблему решил, была ошибка в неправильном маппинге. Большое спасибо за подсказку о правильной передаче объектов с использовании DTO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При добавлении связей один-к-многим допустил ошибку в маппинге сущностей БД.

Часть кода с ошибкой:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "title_lkat")
private Set<Lkat> lkat = new HashSet<>();
```

В следствии чего запись данных в сущность Lkat проводилась без ошибок, т.к. в аннотации `@ManyToOne` не было привязки по атрибуту, а считать из БД Hibernate не мог, т.к. был указан не тот атрибут.

Исправленный код:

Сущность Avtor:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "avtor")
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Lkat> lkat = new HashSet<>();
```

Сущность Lkat:

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonBackReference
private Avtor avtor;
```

**UPDATE**

Для того что бы отправлять только необходимые данные, ввел три класса DTO для каждой сущности БД, пример реализации класса AvtorDTO:

```
public class AvtorDTO {

private String urladdress;

private String avtorname;

private String update_avtor;

private Set<LkatDTO> lkatDTO = new HashSet<>();

public Set<LkatDTO> getLkatDTO() {
    return this.lkatDTO;
}

public void setLkatDTO(Set<LkatDTO> lkatDTO) {
    this.lkatDTO = lkatDTO;
}

public AvtorDTO() {
}

public AvtorDTO(String urladdress) {
    this.urladdress = urladdress;
}

public AvtorDTO(String avtorname, String update_avtor) {
    this.avtorname = avtorname;
    this.update_avtor = update_avtor;
}

public AvtorDTO(String urladdress, String avtorname, String update_avtor, Set<LkatDTO> lkatDTO) {
    this.urladdress = urladdress;
    this.avtorname = avtorname;
    this.update_avtor = update_avtor;
    this.lkatDTO = lkatDTO;

}

public String getUrladdress() {
    return urladdress;
}

public void setUrladdress(String urladdress) {
    this.urladdress = urladdress;
}

public String getAvtorname() {
    return avtorname;
}

public void setAvtorname(String avtorname) {
    this.avtorname = avtorname;
}

public String getUpdate_avtor() {
    return update_avtor;
}

public void setUpdate_avtor(String update_avtor) {
    this.update_avtor = update_avtor;
}

}
```

Так же изменил метод передачи объекта, в котором сразу реализовал формирование объекта класса DTO (возможно это не правильно и стоит реализовать другим способом, но в данном случае все работает), получился следующий код:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getlist")
@ResponseBody
public AvtorDTO getAvtorInClient(String urladdress) {
    List<Avtor> avtorlist = avtorDao.getByUrladdress(urladdress);
    Avtor avtor = avtorlist.get(0);
    Set<LkatDTO> lkatsetDTO = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Lkat> lkatset = avtor.getLkat();
    Iterator<Lkat> itrlkat = lkatset.iterator();
while(itrlkat.hasNext()) {
        Lkat lkat = itrlkat.next();
        Set<Lwork> lworkset = lkat.getLwork();
        Iterator<Lwork> itrlwork = lworkset.iterator();
        Set<LworkDTO> lworksetDTO = new HashSet<>();
        while(itrlwork.hasNext()) {
            Lwork lwork = itrlwork.next();
            LworkDTO lworkDTO = new LworkDTO(lwork.getUrl_lwork(), lwork.getTitle_lwork(), lwork.getDescription_lwork(), lwork.getSize_lwork(), lwork.getUpdate_lwork(), lwork.getAdditional_info(), lwork.getDate_create());
            lworksetDTO.add(lworkDTO);
        }
        LkatDTO lkatDTO = new LkatDTO(lkat.getTitle_lkat(), lkat.getUrl_lkat(), lworksetDTO);
        lkatsetDTO.add(lkatDTO);
    }

    AvtorDTO avtorDTO = new AvtorDTO(avtor.getUrladdress(), avtor.getAvtorname(), avtor.getUpdate_avtor(), lkatsetDTO);

    return avtorDTO;
}
```